# Missing upper left label in seaborn pairplot with corner=True

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) for seaborn shows a pairplot with the upper right half of the plot removed.   It's the result of:

```
sns.pairplot(penguins, corner=True)
```

[image]

Why is the label missing for the upper left plot missing, and how can I get it to display?

Comment: The label is missing since the y-axis for the top plot is not `bill_length_mm`, amd including that as the axis label would be misleading. The diagonal plots have independent y-axes from the other plots, since these are univariate distribution plots showing the distribution of the variables (note how they don't have an axis line at the left like the other plots).

Comment: Of course.  Make total sense.

Comment: But how do we get the label? And how to remove the axis of the column on the right for consistency?